# SignalR in a website project

Tags: signalr

I have a test web application using siglanR that works great. I need to use SignalR in a Website project - it cannot be converted to a web application. I copied my test code into a test website project and I cannot get it to work! I get the 'Cannot read property 'client' of undefined' error.

I have set runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests in the config file.

It's a VS 2010 project. The connection to the hub is successful.

Is there anything that I need to do to get it working in a website project?

Thanks

Comment: Put the code in App_Code.

Comment: @dfowler My problem is very similar with this one. Can you help me with [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311792/signalr-not-working-in-website-but-works-in-web-application)?